# Datepicker Materializecss disabled days function

Tags: datepicker, materialize

I'm working with datepicker from materializecss and I need to disabled all days unless the Monday, at other plugins  I used `'daysOfWeekDisabled'`
parameter but in this case I must to use `disableDayFn: function(){}` and when I insert a parameter all calendar is disabled. Here is an example

```
$('#initCourse').datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: new Date(),
        format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
        disableDayFn: function(){
           return disabled = '0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6'
        }
});
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/yvj56kgp/1/).

`disableDayFn` has a parameter `date` which you can use to find every occurrency of a specific date.

```
disableDayFn: function(date) {
    if(date.getDay() == 1) // getDay() returns a value from 0 to 6, 1 represents Monday
        return false;
    else
        return true;
  }
```

Comment: Oh! Great! I tried to use getDay before to write this post but the plugin showed me an error that this function was not defined but now works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

**It worked fine, but I use another way in case you need to disable one or more dates**

```js
disableDayFn:function (date) {

            let disableListDate = [new Date('2018,12,5').toDateString(),new Date('2018,12,6').toDateString()];

                if(disableListDate.includes(date.toDateString())) {
                    return true
                }else{
                    return false
                }

            }
```